Find MAX and MIN using Excel VLOOKUP by matching the Rows and Results the matching First Column
1st Sheet




1st Sem
2nd Sem
3rd Sem
4th Sem




MATHS
10
20
30
15


ENGLISH
20
35
5
15



Result

Tried to get the result (second picture). Looked for an answer and only got answers which results the marks but not first column matching the mark. Can anyone please help.

What is your excel version?

@Harun24hr, Office Professional Plus 2019, Excel Version 2404

If the 1st list starts in A1 and the subjects of the 2nd list start in G2, in H2 you could use =IFNA(INDEX($B$1:$E$1,,MATCH(MAX(INDEX($B$2:$E$3,MATCH($G2,$A$2:$A$3,0),)),INDEX($B$2:$E$3,MATCH($G2,$A$2:$A$3,0),),0)),""). Copy to the right and replace MAX with MIN. Then copy both down.

In older Excel:
=INDEX($B$1:$E$1,MATCH(MAX(B2:E2),B2:E2,0))
Or =LOOKUP(MAX(B2:E2),B2:E2,$B$1:$E$1)
In case you need it to deal with ties:
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,REPT($B$1:$E$1,B2:E2=MAX(B2:E2)))
(Not sure it requires being entered with ctrl+shift+enter)
And replace MAX by MIN for min header.
Using Office 365:
=@SORTBY($B$1:$E$1,B2:E2,-1)
And remove ,-1 for min header.

Using tables,

and defining the following names,



Name
Refers to




results_for_subject_in_summary
=INDEX(Results, MATCH(Summary[ @[Subject]:[Subject] ],Summary[  [Subject]:[Subject] ], 0), 0)


terms_with_max
=TEXTJOIN(",  ",,IF(results_for_subject_in_summary=MAX(results_for_subject_in_summary),Results[#Headers],  ""))


terms_with_min
=TEXTJOIN(",  ",,IF(results_for_subject_in_summary=MIN(results_for_subject_in_summary),Results[#Headers],  ""))



it will be easier to maintain when adding more subjects.

You need to enter the formulas only in the first row of the table - they will get filled automatically for the rest of the table.
This will be simpler with Microsoft 365 using FILTER.
